# GCP VM network interfaces metadata undefined in cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am following the tutorial here that expands upon setting up a Minecraft server in GCP
https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/brick-by-brick-learn-gcp-by-setting-up-a-minecraft-server

I am trying to create the server startup script as a cloud function, which looks like this

```
/**
* Start the Minecraft server, return the external IP, and create a FW rule
*/
const http = require('http');
const Compute = require('@google-cloud/compute');
const compute = Compute();
const zone = compute.zone('us-west2-a');
const vm = zone.vm('mc-server-v1');
const fwname = 'minecraft-fw-rule-' + Math.floor(new Date() / 1000);
 
async function get_server_ip() {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   vm.getMetadata(function(err, metadata, apiResponse) {
     resolve(metadata.networkInterfaces[0].accessConfigs[0].natIP);
   });
 });
}
 
async function check_if_server_is_ready() {
 const server_ip = await get_server_ip();
 const ready = !!server_ip;
 return ready
}
 
async function sleep(milliseconds) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds);
 });
}
 
exports.startInstance = async function startInstance(req, res) {
 // Start the VM
 const zone = compute.zone('us-west2-a');
 const vm = zone.vm('mc-server-v1');
 console.log('about to start a VM');
 vm.start(function(err, operation, apiResponse) {
   console.log('instance start successfully');
 });
 console.log('the server is starting');
 while(!(await check_if_server_is_ready())) {
   console.log('Server is not ready, waiting 1 second...');
   await sleep(1000);
   console.log('Checking server readiness again...');
 }
 console.log('the server is ready');
 const server_ip = await get_server_ip();
 
 // Record the function caller's IPv4 address
 console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
 sourceIp = req.get('X-Forwarded-For');
 let callerip = req.query.message || req.body.message || sourceIp;
 
 // Set the Firewall configs
 const config = {
   protocols: {tcp: [25565]},
   ranges: [callerip + '/32'],
   tags: ['minecraft-server']
 };
 function callback(err, firewall, operation, apiResponse) {}
 
 // Create the Firewall
 compute.createFirewall(fwname, config, callback);
 
 res.status(200).send('Minecraft Server Started! You are now spending REAL MONEY! <br />' + 'The IP address of the Minecraft server is: ' + server_ip + ':25565<br />Your IP address is ' + callerip + '<br />A Firewall rule named ' + fwname + ' has been created for you.' );
};
```

When I call the cloud function, it throws an error because `metadata.networkInterfaces` in the `vm.getMetadata` callback function is undefined. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my log output

```
D 2020-09-06T22:33:02.269216989Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq Function execution started start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq 
A 2020-09-06T22:33:02.345Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq about to start a VM start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq 
A 2020-09-06T22:33:02.413Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq the server is starting start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq 
A 2020-09-06T22:33:03.329Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq Unhandled rejection start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq 
A 2020-09-06T22:33:03.333Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq 
A 2020-09-06T22:33:03.333Z start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq     at /workspace/index.js:15:40 start-mc-server ztnah459vzjq
```

Comment: Review the error in the 4th line of your log output. Does your cloud function service account have the correct roles to create a Compute Engine instance?

Comment: @JohnHanley in the IAM I see that Google Cloud Functions Service Agent  has one role with the same name, "Google Cloud Functions Service Agent". If I remove the code where the metadata is used to check the IP, it is able to start the instance though.

Comment: The Service Agent is not the service account assigned to your Function. However, you still need to solve the rejection before debugging code that runs after that. Edit your question to improve details and not via comments.

Comment: Is the `new` optional at this line to create a new Compute client? `const compute = Compute();` (I'm not good in NodeJS!)

Comment: Have you followed the steps from this other tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/gaming/minecraft-server)? As mentioned in the one you linked,  you need to have completed this other one before proceeding with this one, as it will help you with the basic stuff, which includes the Compute Engine that you will need to use with functions.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it's funny you should bring that up because the `new` wasn't in the tutorial but I had to add it otherwise I got an error that it was required.

Comment: @gso_gabriel yes, I did all of that

Comment: It might be worth to contact [Google Cloud Support](https://cloud.google.com/support) directly, as you are following the official tutorial and is facing this error. They should be able to provide a better indeep support to you.